# Error in selenium driver select

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera

I have a code that enters a portal with 4 different credentials, the first fails and then the others do everything right.

On the portal page I have the name with the name "cboLocales":

```html
<form action="?action=envia" method="post" name="frmInventario">
    <tr class="texto"> 
      <td width="172" bgcolor="e6e6e6" align="center">Seleccione Locales</td>
      <td width="150" bgcolor="#E6E6E6" align="center">Seleccione Formato de local</td>
      <td width="157" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">Por grupo de Productos</td>
      <td width="126" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">Por grupo de categor&iacute;a</td>
      <td width="121" rowspan="2" valign="bottom">
       <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="texto" value="Ir al Reporte &gt;&gt;" >
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="txt8pt"> 
      <td align="center">
    
          <select name="cboLocales" class="texto">
   <option value="">Seleccione</option>
   <!--<option value="1301a">Total país</option>-->y
            <option value="1302b">Solo Regi&oacute;n Metropolitana</option>
            <option value="1303c">Regiones</option>
   
   <option value="2015">Mall</option>
   
          </select>
      </td>
  </form>
```

And in my code to recognize that select, I have the following:

```html
driver.get(Config.urlStockSB);
Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("cboLocales")));
select.selectByValue(locales.get(i)); //locales desde arreglo en config WebElement btnSubmitStock = driver.findElement(By.name("Submit"));
btnSubmitStock.click();
```

But when going through the select, I get an error that I have not found the name of the select "cboLocales", but it is!

If the first credential is failing, try to change the order of entry of the credentials and even then it fails, please help, I would thank you enough!

PD: Opera use and Netbeans.

Comment: Try to locate the element by class `class="texto"`. Can you provide a link to the page?

Comment: I can not open the page since it is private, but this is the code of the form ... and how could I include the name of the element with the name of the class and the name of the select?

Comment: Try this `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@name='frmInventario']/tr[@class='txt8pt']/td/select")).click();` and then `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@name='frmInventario']/tr[@class='txt8pt']/td/select[@name='cboLocales']")).click();` Between this actions add a `pause(1000);`

Comment: Or `Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@name='frmInventario']/tr[@class='txt8pt']/td/select")));` then `pause(1000)` and then `select.selectByValue(locales.get(i));`

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//form[@name='frmInventario']/tr[@class='txt8pt']/td/select"}
  (Session info: chrome with embedded Chromium 61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: OperaDriver=2.32 (cfa164127aab5f93e5e47d9dcf8407380eb42c50),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Add a pause before you try to locate the element

Comment: is there a frame or iframe?

Comment: (Frame) Try this:
log.info("Pause");
            try{
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//form[@name='frmInventario']/tr[@class='txt8pt']/td/select[@name='cboLocales']")));
            }catch(Exception ex){
                log.error("Error in search");
            }
           Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@name='frmInventario']/tr[@class='txt8pt']/td/select[@name='cboLocales']")));
 select.selectByValue(locales.get(i));

Comment: Same:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//form[@name='frmInventario']/tr[@class='txt8pt']/td/select[@name='cboLocales']"}
  (Session info: chrome with embedded Chromium 61.0.3163.100)

will it be some error of the page? Try the same refresh.

Comment: "Always test your locators in the browser using the dev console, e.g. in Chrome press F12. In the console use $x() to test XPaths and $$() to test CSS selectors. An example, $x("//span[@class='button-inner']""//span[@class='button-inner']"). If it returns 0, you know there's something wrong with your locator. If it returns 1, you are good to go. If it returns more than 1, you will need to verify that the element you are looking for is the first element returned. If it's not, you will need to craft a new locator. – JeffC yesterday"

Comment: @Ywapom    $x("//form[@name='frmInventario']/tr[@class='txt8pt']/td/select[@name='cboLocales']")     It results in "0" :(

Answer (score 0):

you have to wait, until the page is fully loaded

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

WebDriverWait wait5s = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);

driver.get(Config.urlStockSB);
Select select=new Select(wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("cboLocales"))));
select.selectByValue(locales.get(i)); //locales desde arreglo en config WebElement btnSubmitStock = driver.findElement(By.name("Submit"));
btnSubmitStock.click();
```